# Convert workflow to Batch Apex

Tags: workflow, batch

This would be first my batch apex and need urgent help with batch apex code

The requirement is, if

```
(Account: NC EQUALS True) // This is checkbox field
```

AND

```
(Account: Status EQUALS Active) // Status field on Account
```

AND

```
(Case: Case Record Type EQUALS NC Action Plan) // NC Action Plan is a record  type on case
```

Then,
Create a Task which would be on Case Object (Owner is CaseOwner) . Till here , everything worked fine with Workflow.
But, this workflow rule should every year on Anniversary (Anniversary is field on Account)

Please help me to achieve this using Batch Apex and scheduler.

Comment: Why not add a Date type formula field to the Case object to grab the value of the Anniversary off the Account and use that to drive a time-dependent workflow rule?

Comment: Didn't got your statement. Just to add workflow rule should recurs every year on Anniversary

Comment: Right, you won't see the account dates as options under "Add Time Triggers". What it sounds like you need to do is create a formula field on the case that has the same value as the Account's Anniversary date.

Comment: I'm confused, could you please help me write that particular formula.

Comment: Once you go to Setup > Build > Customize > Cases > Fields > New > Formula > Date , the formula is just the name of the Anniversary field. Something like `Account.Anniversary__c`

Comment: Oh, yes, I already have Account.Anniversary__c formula field created on Case. Now, what is the next step ?

Comment: If you go to the workflow and find the "Add Time Triggers" section, you should see the field there.